# Exercises for this muscle

Tags: muscle, workout

there are many who has this muscle.  I don't know the name of the  muscle or how can I do it so open.I cut the picture from a bodybuilder just to show you this.How he did this ?I train my body abs ,chest ,legs, biceps, triceps etc but I want to obtain and those "opened muscles areas" [Image -check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtriM.jpg) . I am not talking about obliques .Thanks[image: the muscle-better image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the Latissimus Dorsi, or most commonly called 'the lats'. A muscle group of the back.

Good exercises to build them are deadlifts, pullups and rows, or any pulling movement really.

Comment: +1 any pulling activity. Though pull-ups (wide grip) target them specifically.

Comment: Good point, added it to my answer.